# PyHive with Kerberos throws Authentication error after few calls

Tags: python, hive, kerberos, pyhive

I am trying to connect to **Hive** using **Python (PyHive Lib)** to read some data and then I further connects it to hive **Flask** to show in Dashboard.

It all works fine for few calls to hive, however soon after that I am getting following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "libs/hive.py", line 63, in <module>
    cur = h.connect().cursor()
  File "libs/hive.py", line 45, in connect
    kerberos_service_name='hive')
  File "/home1/igns/git/emsr/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 94, in connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home1/igns/git/emsr/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 192, in __init__
    self._transport.open()
  File "/home1/igns/git/emsr/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift_sasl/__init__.py", line 79, in open
    message=("Could not start SASL: %s" % self.sasl.getError()))
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not start SASL: Error in sasl_client_start (-1) SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_cdc995595290_51CD7j))
```

**Following is my code**

```
from pyhive import hive
class Hive(object):
    def connect(self):
        return hive.connect(host='hive.hadoop-prod.abc.com',
                            port=10000,
                            database='temp',
                            username='gaurang.shah',
                            auth='KERBEROS',
                            kerberos_service_name='hive')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    h = Hive()
    cur = h.connect().cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from temp.migration limit 1")
    res = cur.fetchall()
    print res
```

**Calling Script**

```
source .venv/bin/activate
for i in {1..50}
do
    python get_hive_data.py
    sleep 300
done
```

**Observation**
When it's working I can see **hive** in service principal when I do **klist** however, I don't when I see above error message.

**Klist when it's working**

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_cdc995595290_XyMnhu
Default principal: gaurang.shah@ABC.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
12/04/2018 14:37:28  12/05/2018 00:37:28  krbtgt/ABC.COM@ABC.COM
    renew until 12/05/2018 14:37:24
12/04/2018 14:39:06  12/05/2018 00:37:28  hive/hive_server.ABC.COM@ABC.COM
    renew until 12/05/2018 14:37:24
```

**Klist when it's not working**

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_cdc995595290_XyMnhu
Default principal: gaurang.shah@ABC.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
12/04/2018 14:37:28  12/05/2018 00:37:28  krbtgt/ABC.COM@ABC.COM
    renew until 12/05/2018 14:37:24
```

**Update:**

So I don't think it's after certain call however, I think it's after certain time. ( I think one hour). I changed the **sleep time** to **3600 sec** and just after first call I started getting error.

This is weird as, ticket for `hive/hive_server.ABC.COM@ABC.COM` was valid for **7 days**

Comment: @karma4917 that's not useful, they are using `pys2` and I am using `pyhive`. And I am able to run successful. it's just after sometime it's started giving error.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post. But if you make a new connection every time you are doing a call, you should resolve the issue.

```
from pyhive import hive
class Hive(object):
    def connect(self):
        return hive.connect(host='hive.hadoop-prod.abc.com',
                            port=10000,
                            database='temp',
                            username='gaurang.shah',
                            auth='KERBEROS',
                            kerberos_service_name='hive')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def newConnect(query):
       h = Hive()
       cur = h.connect().cursor()
       cur.execute(query)
       res = cur.fetchall()
       return res

    myConnectionAndResults = newConnect("select * from temp.migration limit 1")
    print myConnectionAndResults
```

Comment: Error: thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes